# Is it safe to use individual conductors removed from a multi-conductor cable?

Tags: safety, wiring, cables, conductors

I am working on setting up a research lab at a university as a graduate research assistant. We're working on power electronics in a three-phase environment, which means we'll be using at most five high-current wires per connection (three phases, neutral, and earth, though not always all of those). We already have bundled cables picked out—five-conductor "type W" cable ([this](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/8-awg-5c-type-w-portable-power-cable.html) in a few different wire gauges for different applications).

Now, we want to also have single-conductor high-current jumper links, for connecting two boards together (perhaps a rectifier and an inverter, or some power module and a load; we're going for generality here). Ideally, we'd have this in several different colors, but this combination of high current and high flexibility seems to be difficult to find with any sort of variety as to its coloration.

So my question is this: Is it safe to cut the outer sheath off of that type W cable linked above, and use the five interior conductors as single cables in their own right? I'd imagine the insulation is up to the job, since it has to be able to withstand the full rated voltage between two adjacent conductors, but I'm not sure.

We're almost certainly going to just get standard single-color welding cable for these connections, but I can't help but be curious whether this would even be an option.

Answer (score 0):

The wires have adequate insulation.  The sheathing does provide physical protection from abrasion, etc, but shouldn't be necessary in a controlled situation.